# Add tow level nested DataList And The Second level Data Source Take Parameter as the ID Of the first level

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want To Add tow level nested DataList so that the second level data source takes parameters as the ID of the first level.

How can I do this?

Here's my code:

```
</tr>
     </table>
     <br />
           </ItemTemplate>
           <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
           </asp:DataList>
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="63px" Width="619px"></asp:TextBox>
      <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="34px" Text="Comment" Width="116px" />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Social_NetworkConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="MSP_PostGetComments" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
             <SelectParameters>
                                                <!--Want to add parametar from The first Level!-->
             </SelectParameters>
             </asp:SqlDataSource>
             </td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stakcoverflow, good formatting is always your friend. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: `</asp:DataList>`? Where's the content?